# Switching between multiple object graphs in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, uimanageddocument, codable

I’m using CoreData in an iOS app as my relational database.  The relationships between the entities are a little complicated, but only a small number of objects (<40) are created.  I’d like the user to build up the object graph, be able to save the object graph, build a new one, save it, return to the first one, etc.  What is the best pattern for doing this?

I’ve thought about making all of my NSManagedObject subclasses conform to Codable (or make structs for storing each NSManagedObject’s relevant data), serializing all the data and saving to a file, and rebuilding the object graph when decoding.  With this approach, I’d persist the object graph in my custom filetype, but never in CoreData per se.  I suspect this isn’t the best approach for a CoreData application.

I’ve also been reading the docs for UIManagedDocument, but I’m not sure if this is the tool I need.  I can’t find any examples of how it is used, and can’t quite grasp how to implement it (i.e., would I still need to make my NSManagedObject subclasses Codable?)  Any direction or suggestion of how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason the separate “graphs” (presumably a bunch of inter-related objects) can’t coexist in the same persistent store?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that will work.  I want the user to also be able to save an object, modify it, save it as a different version, then return to the original save etc.  If that were in one persistent store, it would be inconsistent.